# Spring Boot Admin with Docker Swarm Unable to pull Health Metrics

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I am trying to get spring boot admin to work in a docker swarm cluster using a zookeeper discovery service mechanism to ensure that all clients are dynamically discovered once connected to zookeeper.  Problem is it appears springboot admin is unable to reach the health actuator endpoints on the clients due to a connection refused even though all docker services are using the same overlay network and each container can ping one another which ive verified via docker exec -it  ping  to ensure they are all reachable from one another.

Ive also verified that the clients and the admin service's are properly connecting to zookeeper and that zookeeper + admin dashboard are infact seeing those clients as registered.

To recreate this issue ive created a simple docker compose that deploys two spring boot admin apps with the actuators enabled over the same overlay network via the compose file below:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo1
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda5v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo2
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda6v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888

    nspadmin:
        image: admin:77
        ports:
            - "9084:8080"
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        depends_on:
            - "zoo1"
            - "zoo2"
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            mode: global
        environment:
            ZK_HOST: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182
            SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ssldev
networks:
    nsp_test:
      external:
        name: nsp_test
```

From this configuration I see both spring admin dashboards registered in zookeeper and display as OFFLINE (since it cant reach the /health actuator)

The following two addresses are what it registers for the clients in SBA.
https://10.255.0.19:8080/ OFFLINE
https://10.255.0.20:8080/ OFFLINE

The exception I get.

```
2018-12-31 04:20:31.926  INFO 1 --- [    updateTask1] d.c.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater    : Couldn't retrieve status for Application [id=28eab1e1, name=nsp-admin, managementUrl=https://10.255.0.20:8080/, healthUrl=https://10.255.0.20:8080/health, serviceUrl=https://10.255.0.20:8080/]
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://10.255.0.20:8080/health": Connect to 10.255.0.20:8080 [/10.255.0.20] failed: connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.255.0.20:8080 [/10.255.0.20] failed: connect timed out
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:549) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.web.client.ApplicationOperations.doGet(ApplicationOperations.java:68) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.6.jar!/:1.5.6]
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.web.client.ApplicationOperations.getHealth(ApplicationOperations.java:58) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.6.jar!/:1.5.6]
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.queryStatus(StatusUpdater.java:111) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.6.jar!/:1.5.6]
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdater.updateStatus(StatusUpdater.java:65) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.6.jar!/:1.5.6]
        at de.codecentric.boot.admin.registry.StatusUpdateApplicationListener$1.run(StatusUpdateApplicationListener.java:47) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.6.jar!/:1.5.6]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to 10.255.0.20:8080 [/10.255.0.20] failed: connect timed out
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar!/:4.5.3]
```

My SBA Configuration yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        prefer-ip: false
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${DB_URL}
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  application:
    name: nsp-admin
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
    zookeeper:
      connect-string: ${ZK_HOST}
      discovery:
        uri-spec: https://{address}:{port}
        metadata:
          management:
            context-path: /
          health:
            path: /health

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

#security.require-ssl: true
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key-store-type: PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store: *****
server.ssl.key-store-password: *****
```

**UPDATE**
After debugging the issue a bit more I realized it without a doubt has to do with the hostname/IP the clients are registering in zookeeper.

When i perform a curl using the docker id's as the hostnames the /health api returns when performing the curl from SBA to the Client container id.

This Works:
docker exec -it 8403c5001b9e curl -k https://bf41c73af594:8080/health

This does not work results in a timeout: docker exec -it 8403c5001b9e curl -k https://10.255.0.20:8080/health

Is it possible to force zookeeper to register the hostname or the containerid instead?

**UPDATE**
Setting spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instanceHost: ${HOSTNAME} in my application.yml resolves the issue.  It forces the correct containerId to be registered to zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all these circuses. In Docker, there is a concept called service discovery. It is a local DNS resolution taken care by docker.

You can either use the container name or specify an alias instead of IP/container id as these will change every time.

#### Method 1:

By default, docker adds network name with service name to name a container. You can fix a name to the container by using `container_name` keyword in decker-compose. Then you can use that name instead of IP. This will get the respective containers resolved.

An example compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo1
        container_name: zoo1
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda5v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo2
        container_name: zoo2
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda6v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888

    nspadmin:
        image: admin:77
        ports:
            - "9084:8080"
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        depends_on:
            - "zoo1"
            - "zoo2"
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            mode: global
        environment:
            ZK_HOST: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182
            SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ssldev
networks:
    nsp_test:
      external:
        name: nsp_test
```

Now you can reach **zoo1** and **zoo2** as `zoo1`,`zoo2`. ***Not suitable for swarm mode as `container_name` is ignored***

#### Method 2: (Recommended for docker swarm mode)

You can specify alias for each host and can access that service by using the alias.

An example compose file:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo1
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - zoo1
                    - zoo.1
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda5v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo2
        networks:
            default:
                aliases:
                    - zoo2
                    - zoo.2
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda6v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888

    nspadmin:
        image: admin:77
        ports:
            - "9084:8080"
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        depends_on:
            - "zoo1"
            - "zoo2"
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            mode: global
        environment:
            ZK_HOST: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182
            SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ssldev
networks:
    default:
      external:
        name: nsp_test
```

Here `zoo1` can be resolved as `zoo1`,`zoo.1`,`zoo1.nsp_test`,`zoo.1.nsp_test`. The same goes for `zoo2`. ***suitable for swarm mode as well.***

#### Method 3:

If you know what is the name of the service that is getting created then you can use that as well to resolve the container.

For example:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    zoo1:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo1
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda5v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 1
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888

    zoo2:
        image: zookeeper:3.4.12
        hostname: zoo2
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.hostname == nj51nreda6v]
        environment:
            ZOO_MY_ID: 2
            ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888 server.2=0.0.0.0:2888:3888

    nspadmin:
        image: admin:77
        ports:
            - "9084:8080"
        networks:
            - nsp_test
        depends_on:
            - "zoo1"
            - "zoo2"
        deploy:
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            mode: global
        environment:
            ZK_HOST: zoo1:2181,zoo2:2182
            SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: ssldev
networks:
    nsp_test:
      external:
        name: nsp_test
```

Let us assume that the above config creates containers with name `zoo1_nsp_test` and `zoo2_nsp_test`. You can resolve the containers by using these name as well. ***Not suitable for swarm node as container name differs from host to host.***

***Note:

All the above methods work only if the containers are connected to same network.***

References:

1. [Compose file version 3 reference#container_name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name)
2. [Compose file version 3 reference#aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)
3. [service discovery](https://success.docker.com/article/ucp-1-1-service-discovery)
4. [Load balancing, service discovery and security](https://blog.octo.com/en/how-does-it-work-docker-part-3-load-balancing-service-discovery-and-security/)

Comment: What you posted doesnt address the problem.  As shown in the above post the issue isnt resolving the zookeeper hosts, the problem was that the incorrect hostname/IP was being registered to zookeeper rather than the actual containerId.  Even if I used your approach it wouldnt resolve the issue.  Instead specifying the property spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instanceHost: ${HOSTNAME} in my application.yml in my spring containers resolves the correct containerid to zookeeper.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Should I delete the answer or keep it in such case? I hope the firewall has whitelisted the necessary ports and ips as well.

Comment: No worries, keep the answer, it honestly could help someone with issues related to docker DNS resolution problems with Java.  Specifying alias's is still important for that.  Im wondering though in the example you showed above how network alias is applied to a globally deployed docker service?  It worked in your example above only if the service im assuming is deployed as a single replicated instance rather than globally on all docker nodes in the swarm.  How does the alias get resolved then?

Comment: By default when you deploy a service to docker swarm the service gets deployed with endpoint_mode as vip which means docker will allocate one virtual ip for the service and maps all the service replicas to that ip. So this alias will point to that ip which is routed to any docker service by docker dns. There is another option called dnsrr which assigns individual ips to each service and the alias will be pointed to different ip by docker dns each time you query it based on round robin algorithm.